# Angular display multiple templates based on condition

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I've an button and I'm displaying tooltip based on the condition, now I've single condition for which I'm displaying tooltip, now I've other set of condition for which I need to display different message

```
<div *ngIf="!assessmentDetailsObj" placement="top-right" [mtTooltip]="(!lob || lob === undefined) ? disabledLOBContent : ''">
          <button
            *ngIf="!assessmentDetailsObj"
            [disabled]="(!lob || lob === undefined)"
            class="btn btn-primary"
            aria-label="Accept"
            (click)="create()"
          >
            Create
          </button>
        </div>
        <ng-template #disabledLOBContent>Please Select LOB</ng-template>
```

now I want to add other set of condition

```
[mtTooltip]="isTrueSet ? refVar : ''"
<ng-template #refVar>Please select Endpoints</ng-template>
```

Can I bind `[mtTooltip]` to a function and inside function can i check for multiple conditions and based on that can i display messages?

Comment: side note: `(!lob || lob === undefined)` can be simplified to `(!lob)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of making multiple templates and making your condition complex, you may actually put your conditions inside your template, if your templates are simple enough:

```
<ng-template #disabledLOBContent>
  <ng-container *ngIf="myContition1">Please Select LOB</ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="myContition2">An other message</ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="myContition3">An other diffrent message</ng-container>
</ng-template>
```